# Send C2DM Message

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Hello I want to send a C2DM message. To receive the message I use the Chrome to Phone application which I download from http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/checkout
There I change the sender id to another gmail id which I used to sign up this application (role account used for sending messages). And also get the auth token and registration id for the same mail id using the android code which I download from above. But when I am sending c2dm message using curl as shown below it return 401 error and says that Unauthorized. Can some one help me to pointing out where I am making wrong.

```
curl --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=**authFromRegistrationAbove**" "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send" -d registration_id=**phoneRegistrationId(reciever)** -d "data.message=Hello" -d collapse_key=message -k
```

Comment: I just tested your curl syntax with my own registration id and auth token, and it worked perfectly.  You might want to double-check that your registration id is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs authorization. Have you registered yourself with Google? You need to sign up with them to receive registration IDs when a user logs into his/her device.

Here is that error code from the docs:
401 Indicates that the ClientLogin AUTH_TOKEN used to validate the sender is invalid.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in the above comment that I have signed up my application with google and I also use the same mail to to register my application with C2DM server and get the auth token and registration id as a response. After that I use the same auth token and registration id to send message using curl. But all the time I am getting the 401 error.